# Why does my dark mode script in the navigation bar?

Tags: html, css

Could someone help me with my dark mode script? I made this HTML and CSS that should give the user a darker blue (#12355B) when it is in dark mode. It just gives me the same blue as the one from light mode (#43BBFF). Thanks in advance!

```css
        body {
            background: #F5F5F5;
            font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif;
            color: black
            }
            
        @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
        body {
            background: #333;
            color: #F5F5F5
        }
        .topnav {
            overflow: hidden;
            border-radius: 8px;
            background-color: #12355B;
            position: sticky;
            top: 0px;
        }
        }  
        .topnav {
            overflow: hidden;
            border-radius: 8px;
            background-color: #43BBFF;
            position: sticky;
            top: 0px;
        }    
            
        .topnav a {
            float: left;
            display: block;
            color: #E0E0E0;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 12px 14px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 17px;
            font-weight: 400;
        }
```

Comment: add } to the end of your code to close @media

Comment: The definition outside the `@media` aims all cases whereas `@media` aims only `prefers-color-scheme: dark` and the definition outside the @media overrides the "dark case". You should put the default color above the `@media` or put it in `prefers-color-scheme: light` mode.

Comment: Thank you! It worked!